# Using NT Auth with CruiseControl and Subversion

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to have my source control block in my ccnet.config file access SVN without passing in the credentials. Instead I want the user that is configured in the ccnet service to be used.

So, I just didn't include the username and password tags in the sourcecontrol block thinking it would work.

It doesn't and instead I get the error:

> Source control operation failed: svn: OPTIONS of 'http://xxx.xxx.com:8888/svn/SourceCode/Trunk': authorization failed (http://xxx.xxx.com:8888)

If I then put in the username and password tags into the source control block, and use the exact same credentials that are configured for the service, it then works fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to log in to the box as that user (or do a RunAs with the svn client) and do an svn update or other svn action to get SVN to prompt you for your credentials to that repository.  And when you are prompted, tell SVN to cache the credentials.

Comment: I'm puzzling out the same problem as the OP and had automatically done what you suggested, but SVN already had my credentials cached.