# Cruise Control.net and subversion issue

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I have a intervalTrigger that runs off subversion source control.

I update subversion but it doesn't trigger the build.

I have the exact same setup on another server and it works.

How can I troubleshoot this?  Is there a log I can look into?  I don't see any error messages.

The new server is VMWare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CruiseControl.NET writes two log files, one for debugging and one for its cron jobs. Both must be enabled via the config file, and both are in the CruiseControl.NET install directory.

Explained [here](http://build.subtextproject.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Server%20Application%20Config%20File.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the clocks are set correctly?

Cruisecontrol doesn't look at the last revision in the repository (HEAD), but the last revision committed before the current time on the server. It passes this time to the 'svn log' call used for obtaining change info.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you may be encountering is authentication - if you're attaching to Subversion via the SSL layer, you need to accept the authenticator on the host machine.  I can't find a good reference to this online, and I don't have a set of notes about it, but it's pretty obvious from the ccnet.log file.

The other possibility is that you just need to [cache credentials on the CC.NET server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928044/using-nt-auth-with-cruisecontrol-and-subversion)